Using 'slice_max()' in for loop
I'm trying to create new dataframes with the top three values for each column across a dataframe.
probUnweighted <- data.frame(
Sample1 = c(0.9, 0.2, 0.03, 0.1, 0.5, 0.09), 
Sample2 = c(0.045, 0.11, 0.006, 0.0036, 0.005, 0.025), 
Sample3 = c(0.05, 0.21, 0.06, 0.0067, 0.0105, 0.1025)
)

I've written a for loop to create new dataframes for each column/sample
library(dplyr); library(tibble); library(tidyr)

for (i in names(probUnweighted)){
assign(paste0("df_",i), probUnweighted %>% 
        select(i) %>%  
        slice_max(order_by = i, n = 3)
  )
}

If I stop at select(i) I generate three dataframes as expected, df_Sample1 and so on. However, the slice_max keeps giving me an error,
Error in `slice_max()`:
! Can't compute indices.
Caused by error:
! `order_by` must have size 6, not size 1.


i is a string.  select expects the column name as a "symbol".  You're a victim of tidyverse's NSE.

it's been especially bewildering, that select(i) behaves as expected, but not within slice_max()

@ChrisStantis select() is forgiving with strings, but you should really use any_of() or all_of() if you are using a character vector in select().

Does this give you what you want?
lapply(
  names(probUnweighted),
  function(x) {
    probUnweighted %>% 
      select(all_of(x)) %>% 
      slice_max(order_by = .data[[x]], n = 3)
  }
)
[[1]]
  Sample1
1     0.9
2     0.5
3     0.2

[[2]]
  Sample2
1   0.110
2   0.045
3   0.025

[[3]]
  Sample3
1  0.2100
2  0.1025
3  0.0600

Though I agree with LMc's implicit assumption that your data would be tidier if you pivoted into long format.

probUnweighted %>% 
   reframe(across(everything(), ~head(sort(.x, TRUE), 3)))

  Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
1     0.9   0.110  0.2100
2     0.5   0.045  0.1025
3     0.2   0.025  0.0600


If you pivot your data to a long format then you can do this using a by group:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(probUnweighted, everything()) |>
  slice_max(value, n = 3, by = name) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_fn = list) |> 
  unnest(everything())
#   Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
#     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     0.9   0.11    0.21 
# 2     0.5   0.045   0.102
# 3     0.2   0.025   0.06 

